# PowerShell: Iteratively remove all empty subfolders from a folder subtree

Tags: powershell, directory, is-empty, subtree, delete-directory

I wrote the following script to recursively remove any folders that are empty. I have tested this in a sandbox and it appears to be safe. That is, it will only remove a folder if it is empty and it will only navigate within subfolders within the starting parent folder and won't inadvertently go further up in the directory.

So, if you could take a quick look at my script and tell me if you see any dangers, I would appreciate. Thank you!

```
$isEmpty=1
$iteration=0
while ($isEmpty) {
    $isEmpty=0
    $iteration++
    
    get-childitem -Directory -Force -recurse | ForEach-Object {
        $count=(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Force).count
        if ($count -eq 0) {
            $isEmpty=1
            Write-Host "$iteration`t$count`t$_"
            $path="\\?\"+$_.FullName
            $folder= Get-item -Path $path
            $folder.Attributes = $folder.Attributes -band -bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly
            $folder.Attributes = $folder.Attributes -band -bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden

            Remove-Item -Force -LiteralPath $path
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Obvious one without much though would be to run `Remove-Item -Force -LiteralPath $path -WhatIf` and inspect the output on the prod path after ensuring you have data there backed up for restore/recovery just in case too and confirm you see no gotchas in the output there with `-whatif` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$isEmpty=1`, `$isEmpty=0`

While `1` and `0` do work as *implicit* Boolean values, it's better to use Booleans *explicitly*, i.e. `$true` and `$false`: `$isEmpty = $true`, `$isEmpty = $false`

---

> `Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName`

If you know paths to be *literal* (verbatim) paths rather than [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expressions, use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`.

---

> `Get-Item -Path $path`

The `-LiteralPath` recommendation applies equally, but, more importantly:

- Perhaps surprisingly - see [GitHub issue #6502](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6502) - even when targeting a file-system item by *explicit, literal path* - `-Force` is needed to target *hidden* items with [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Item) or [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem).

---

> `$folder.Attributes = $folder.Attributes -band -bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly` [...]

You do *not* need to explicitly clear the `Hidden` and `ReadOnly` attributes from file-system items in order for [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Remove-Item) to remove them - using `-Force` is sufficient.

---

**Taking a step back:**

You can avoid *multiple* traversals of your folder subtree if you process directories (folders) *bottom up*, i.e. if you start with the *leaf* directories in the directory subtree and iteratively traverse upward:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Force -Recurse | 
  Sort-Object -Descending { ($_.FullName -split '[\\/]').Count } |
  Where-Object { 
    if (-not ($_ | Get-ChildItem -Force | Select-Object -First 1)) {
      $_ | Remove-Object -Force -WhatIf
    }
  }
```

Note:

- The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.
- That said, given the *iterative* nature of your task, `-WhatIf` will only show you the empty *leaf* directories that would get deleted and not any of their *ancestors* that would also get deleted *as a result of deleting any leaves*.

  - Only actually *running* the command (by removing `-WhatIf`) will tell you the actual results.
  - Therefore, it's best to *keep a backup of your entire directory subtree* while tweaking the code.